# Disable cardreaders on Lenovo T500 in BIOS

Tags: bios, thinkpad, card-reader

I have a lenovo T500 that I'm trying to do a DBAN on (formatting program)
it stalls cause it can't handle the card reader in the lenovo..
I was suggested by people on the DBAN forum to go find the cardreader in BIOS and turn it off.

thats where I'm at, I've searched all through my BIOS.. I can't seem to find the possibility to turn off any card reader or media card, og anything resembling that name.

Comment: Sounds like you answered your own question, it cannot be disabled in the bios? If the card reader is attached to the motherboard using a cable, that would be you next solution to unplug it, but would require disassembly of the notebook, post the full model number of your t500.

Answer (score 1):

As of writing this I'm wiping out hard drive on Lenovo T500 using DBAN. SD card reader can and must be disabled from BIOS. The correct setting can be found under Security. Just disable Memory Card Slot.